# What is the closed-form solution for the following problem?

Tags: closed-form

What is the closed-form expression to the following problem

[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.  Images are not terribly searchable, and cause problems for folk who access this site using screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you state what exactly C is (I suppose it stands for cash, but what about it exactly)?

Comment: I'd start by noting that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_i}{(1+r)^i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_{2i-1}}{(1+r)^{2i-1}}+\frac{C_{2i}}{(1+r)^{2i}},$$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_i}{(1+r)^i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_{2i-1}}{(1+r)^{2i-1}}+\frac{C_{2i-1}}{(1+r)^{2i}},$$ or $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_i}{(1+r)^i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_{2i-1}(1+r)}{(1+r)^{2i}}+\frac{C_{2i-1}}{(1+r)^{2i}},$$ and so $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_i}{(1+r)^i}=(2+r)\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{C_{2i-1}}{(1+r)^{2i}}.$$ Then note that $C_{2i-1}=C(1+g)^{i-1}$ for all $i,$ which should let you turn it into a geometric series.